# Converting String currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers

How can I convert numbers from a string, and return the same format?

```
//INPUT as STRING
var dollar1 = "US $59.99 - 69.99 / piece"
var dollar2 = "US $237.50 - 277.50 /lot"
var US_to_MUR_rate = 35;
//FUNCTION
function convert ( string, rate) {
//what should be here ?

return str_converted;
}

//EXPECTED OUPUT as STRING:
var ruppes1 = convert (dollar1, US_to_MUR_rate);
var ruppes2 = convert (dollar2, US_to_MUR_rate);
console.log(rupees1);
"MUR Rs2099.65 - 2449.65 / piece"
console.log(rupees2);
"MUR Rs8032.5 - 9712.5 /lot"
```

Comment: use `Number()` or parse it according could be int or float then do computation.to make it string just add ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//INPUT as STRING
var dollar1 = "US $59.99 - 69.99 / piece"
var dollar2 = "US $237.50 - 277.50 / lot"
var dollar3 = "US $54 - 60 / lot"
var US_to_MUR_rate = 35;

//FUNCTION
function convert ( string, rate) {
  return string
    .replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g, function(match) {
      return (parseFloat(match) * US_to_MUR_rate).toFixed(2);
    })
    .replace(/US \$/, 'MUR Rs');
}

//EXPECTED OUPUT as STRING:
var rupees1 = convert (dollar1, US_to_MUR_rate);
var rupees2 = convert (dollar2, US_to_MUR_rate);
var rupees3 = convert (dollar3, US_to_MUR_rate);

console.log(rupees1);
console.log(rupees2);
console.log(rupees3);
```

Comment: But it doesn't work anymore with integer. Please update

Answer (score 1):

of course certain part of this answer is explicitly coded, unless you wanted it differently

```js
var dollar1 = "US $59.99 - 69.99 / piece"
var dollar2 = "US $237.50 - 277.50 /lot"
var US_to_MUR_rate = 35;

function convert(string, rate){
 var converted_price = string.match(/(\d+)\.(\d*)/g).map(function(number){
  return (number*rate).toFixed(2)
 })
 var unit = string.match(/(\/\s*\w+)/g)
 return "MUR Rs"+converted_price.join(' - ')+" "+unit
}

var rupees1 = convert(dollar1, US_to_MUR_rate);
var rupees2 = convert(dollar2, US_to_MUR_rate);
console.log(rupees1);
console.log(rupees2);
```